# MATLAB: Create a block diagonal matrix with same repeating block

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have a matrix **K** of dimensions *n x n*. I want to create a new block diagonal matrix **M** of dimensions *N x N*, such that it contains *d* blocks of matrix **K** as its diagonal.

I would have directly used *M = blkdiag(K,K,K)* etc. had *d* been smaller. Unfortunately, *d* is very large and I don't want to manually write the formula with *d* exactly same arguments for the *blkdiag()* function.

Is there any shorter, smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

you can use `kron` for that.

```
M = kron(X,Y)
```

returns the Kronecker tensor product of X and Y. The result is a large array formed by taking all possible products between the elements of X and those of Y. If X is m-by-n and Y is p-by-q, then kron(X,Y) is m*p-by-n*q. So in your case something like this will do:

```
M = kron(eye(L),K)
```

with `L` the # of blocks.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @natan. I tried a couple of combinations and figured that following gives me what I'm looking for - `M = kron(eye(d),K)`

Answer (score 3):

```
tmp = repmat({K},d,1);
M = blkdiag(tmp{:});
```

You should never use eval, or go into for loops unnecessarily. 
Kron is a very elegant way. 
Just wanted to share this as it also works.

Comment: Actually, this is faster than using `Kron`:  
`K=rand(3);`
`tic;G = kron(eye(2000),K);toc`
Elapsed time is 0.122015 seconds.
` tic;tmp = repmat({K},2000,1);M = blkdiag(tmp{:});toc`
Elapsed time is 0.036623 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

d=5; K=eye(3); T = cell(1,d);

for j=1:d
    T{j} =K;
end

M = blkdiag(T{:})

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'A,';
s = repmat(s,[1,n2]);
s = ['B=blkdiag(', s(1:end-1),');'];
eval(s);
```

It can be faster than using kron-eye.

Answer (score 0):

A "for" loop may might help. Like:

```
M = k;
for i=1:N/n - 1
    M=blkdiag(M,k);
end
```