# Create a block diagonal and subdiagonal with a repeating block in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

Suppose I have an `n`-by-`n` matrix `A` and an `n`-by-`n` matrix `B`. I want to create a block matrix `C` consisting of `N` blocks of matrix `A` as a diagonal and (`N`-1) blocks of matrix `B` as a subdiagonal below the `A` diagonal.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370371/matlab-create-a-block-diagonal-matrix-with-same-repeating-block) gives answers for only the block diagonal case, which are all great. Now I want to add a block subdiagonal, which command in Matlab should I use?

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how to create a matrix `C` with `A` on its diagonal (of size `nN`-by-`nN`), you can also create a matrix `D` of smaller size (`n(N-1)`-by-`n(N-1)`) with `B` on its diagonal, then you just need to add `D` at the right sub-matrix of `C`:

```
C( (n+1):end, (n+1):end ) = C( (n+1):end, (n+1):end ) + D;
```

Alternatively, using [`kron`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html):

```
C = kron( eye(n), A ) + kron( diag(ones(n-1,1), -1), B );
```

You might be better off using sparse matrices here

```
C = kron( speye(n), A ) + kron( spdiag(ones(n-1,1), -1, n, n), B );
```

Comment: Thanks. The part "add D at the right sub-matrix of C" is what I was not familiar with!

Comment: Thanks for the alternative too!