# lsqlin optimized calculation (matlab)

Tags: matlab, optimization, least-squares

I am calculating the solution of a constrained linear least-squares problem as follows:

```
lb = zeros(7,1);
ub = ones(7,1);
for i = 1:size(b,2)
   x(:,i) = lsqlin(C,b(:,i),[],[],[],[],lb,ub);
end
```

where `C` is `m x 7` and `b` is `m x n`. `n` is quite large leading to a slow computation time. Is there any way to speed up this procedure and get rid of the slow `for` loop. I am using `lsqlin` instead of `pinv` or `\` because I need to constrain my solution to the boundaries of 0–1 (`lb` and `ub`).

Comment: You can always try to switch the default-solver. Try ```'interior-point```. Not sure what that loop is for and how you expect us to work on it.

Comment: I tried the different solvers but the problem is the same. I am using the for loop because the if I try to give `x = lsqlin(C,b,[],[],[],[],lb,ub);` I am getting a `Inner matrix dimensions must agree.` error. On the other hand, if I use `pinv(C)*b` or `C \ b` it works like a charm but for the `lsqlin` I need to do it through the `for` loop and since I need the constraints I need to use the `lsqlin`. Therefore, I am just asking if there is any posibility to optimize or discard the `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for` loop is not necessarily the reason for any slowness – you're not pre-allocating and [`lsqlin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqlin.html) is probably printing out a lot of stuff on each iteration. However, you may be able to speed this up by turning your `C` matrix into a sparse block diagonal matrix, `C2`, with `n` identical blocks ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26612729/2278029)). This solves all `n` problems in one go. If the new `C2` is not sparse you may use a lot more memory and the computation may take much longer than with the `for` loop.

```
n = size(b,2);
C2 = kron(speye(n),C);
b2 = b(:);
lb2 = repmat(lb,n,1); % or zeros(7*n,1);
ub2 = repmat(ub,n,1); % or ones(7*n,1);
opts = optimoptions(@lsqlin,'Algorithm','interior-point','Display','off');
x = lsqlin(C2,b2,[],[],[],[],lb2,ub2,[],opts);
```

Using [`optimoptions`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optimoptions.html), I've [specified the algorithm](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqlin.html#inputarg_options) and set `'Display'` to `'off'` to make sure any outputs and warnings don't slow down the calculations.

On my machine this is 6–10 times faster than using a `for` loop (with proper pre-allocation and setting options). This approach assumes that the sparse `C2` matrix with `m*n*7` elements can fit in memory. If not, a `for` loop based approach will be the only option (other than writing your own specialized version of `lsqlin` or taking advantage any other spareness in the problem).

Comment: many thanks for your answer. Your solution seems to make the trick ;-). I had messages off as well but not pre-allocation (next thing I was planning to try) while using the sparse block diagonal matrix is a trick that I wan not aware of and it seems to help a lot. Thanks for your help once more.

Comment: just another question. How optimal, is the use of the sparse block diagonal matrix, memory wise. Because for example, in my case I have to deal with matrices of size `C` (193200x7) `b` (193200x16450) or bigger, my bad that I did not mention that earlier. As you can understand trying your solution in practice, now I have the issue with the memory (250Gb are not enough for the C2 pre-allocation). Any hint for that?

Comment: I was assuming `m` was smaller than `n` because you indicated that `n` was large in your question. Your sparse `C2` will need approximately the same memory as a a 193200x7x16450 array (as opposed to a full array that would be 16450 times larger than that!). Your `b` is already larger than the default maximum array size in my version of Matlab (you probably had to go into the preference to change the limit). A `for` loop is the way to go if you are memory bound, unless other parts of the system are sparse.

Comment: I see. Thanks again for your time ;-)