# MATLAB Concatenating Functions

Tags: matlab, function, concatenation

I have a function `@(x) f(x)` that returns `3-by-3` matrix. I want to define another function `@(x) F(x)` that returns a `3*n-by-3*n`, with `f(x)` repeated `n` times along the diagonal, for an arbitrary `n`.

This can be done with arrays (instead of functions) pretty simply:

```
n = 5; 
A = repmat({magic(3)},[1,n]); 
B = blkdiag(A{:})
```

But for functions, there is subtlety since arguments need to be passed. My naive attempts were unsuccessful:

```
f=@(x) magic(3);

F=@(x) blkdiag(repmat({f(x)},[1,n]))
F=@(x) blkdiag({repmat({f(x)},[1,n])})
F=@(x) blkdiag(repmat({feval(@(xx) f(xx),x)},[1,n]))
```

In general, are there elegant ways to concatenate/combine/repeat a function?

Comment: Any specific reason why you must use function handles? Why not nested functions? Function handles are very difficult to debug. You may find some useful hints [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28798626/3372061).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370371/matlab-create-a-block-diagonal-matrix-with-same-repeating-block

Comment: You're absolutely right @Dev-iL ... there's no reason I need function handles and the "elegant way to concatenate/combine/repeat a function" is certainly to just define a function rather than attempt to code-golf with function handles. I was stuck in one frame of thought I suppose. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks @beaker for the link as well!